# Importing Weka in Java on GAE server

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, weka

I have an Android app that sends data to `GAE`. The code on `GAE` does some processing and returns the results to the Android app.

On server side, I am using `Weka classes` to process the data. On `App Engine log viewer`, I get this error.
[Screenshot of Error in App Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndLga.jpg)

I suspect that the `Weka.jar` is missing on `App Engine server`. Is there a way to add it?

Thanks,

Comment: I tested my servlet locally before deploying to GAE and it worked fine. I didn't expect this problem when putting codes on GAE. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone seeking answer to this question. If using Eclipse, You need to copy the required jar(s) to the /WEB-INF/lib folder manually.